# Why I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError after update Apache Tomcat 7 to 9?

Tags: java, oracle, apache, tomcat, java-8

After update Apache Tomcat from version 7.0.62 to 9.010 I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor
```

Something is wrong with the new version or with my configuration. Practically the backend works fine except by this.

The problem dissapear when I use the 7 version newly, but I need to use 9.

Can you help?

This is the full Exception

```
Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error
Tipo Informe de Excepción

mensaje Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor

descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
causa raíz

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor
    org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.execute(Request.java:177)
    com.desafioguerreros.infrastructure.payments.universalpay.UniversalPayPaymentsServices.postToApi(UniversalPayPaymentsServices.java:153)
    com.desafioguerreros.infrastructure.payments.universalpay.UniversalPayPaymentsServices.buildPaymentForm(UniversalPayPaymentsServices.java:233)
    com.desafioguerreros.events.core.EventRestFacade.onlinePaymentForm(EventRestFacade.java:1405)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de diario del servidor.
```

Comment: did you add jars to the lib folder of the TC7 instance you didn't add to the lib folder of the new Tomcat?

Comment: application WAR include the jars... I don't know if you talking of other jars...

Comment: are you building a project with ant or maven and seeing this error ? could be a ant/maven version issue if that is the case.

Comment: Which version of fluent-hc are you using?

Comment: hi  @KoheiTAMURA im using fluent-hc-4.5.5